# Can you chain killstreak rewards together in Call of Duty Modern Warfare II?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

By this I mean, say you have your 3 killstreaks, and first highest killstreak is Chopper Gunner (imagine your other two are EMP and Tac Nuke). Ok, so you have you 11 kills in a row, and you have chopper gunner available. You begin running around shooting your gun into the air to attract enemy attention. You are shot and killed.

Now, you respawn, with your chopper gunner available. You find a nice quiet place to hide to activate your chopper gunner.

Now, imagine you are really good at chopper gunner and quickly rack up 13 kills with chopper gunner. You manage to get through the whole killstreak without having your Chopper Gunner shot down AND you do not die while using chopper gunner. Remember, you killed 13 people with chopper gunner.

**THE QUESTION**: WILL I HAVE EARNED ***ANOTHER*** CHOPPER GUNNER AS A RESULT OF MY *FIRST* CHOPPER GUNNER?

Comment: Wow, I never thought to do this.  I know you can chain them to get higher up (pred -> chopper), but I never thought of dying and reusing.

Comment: @tzenes This is the first thing I tried once I unlocked decent killstreak rewards and I was both disappointed I couldn't do it and happy others couldn't do it to me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kills you get using killstreak rewards gained on a previous life after you respawn do not count towards new killstreaks.

So to answer your main question: no.

Also see here: [Which Modern Warfare 2 Killstreak Rewards count towards your current kill streak?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/which-modern-warfare-2-killstreak-rewards-count-towards-your-current-kill-streak/4641#4641)

Comment: ok, I figured this was the case. I just played in a game a while back where it seemed like every minute or so there was *another* chopper gunner. I wasn't paying attention to the name of the person/people calling them in so I didn't know if it was the same player or not.